# Functional Programming (Currying) in C / Issue with Types

Tags: c, gcc, types, functional-programming, function-pointers

As a dyed-in-the-wool functional programmer I find it hard not to try to shoehorn my favourite paradigm into whatever language I'm using. While writing some C I found I'd like to curry one of my functions, and then pass around the partially applied function. After reading [Is there a way to do currying in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023261/is-there-a-way-to-do-currying-in-c) and heeding the warnings at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*function) (int);

function g (int a) {
    int f (int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
    return f;
}

int f1(function f){
    return f(1);}

int main () {
    printf ("(g(2))(1)=%d\n",f1(g(2)));
}
```

Which runs as expected. However, my original program works with `double`s and so I thought I'd just change the appropriate types and I'd be fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double (*function) (double);

function g (double a) {
    double f (double b) {
        return a+b;
    }
    return f;
}

double f1(function f){
    return f(1);}

int main () {
    printf ("(g(2))(1)=%e\n",f1(g(2)));
}
```

This produces things like:

```
bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault: 11
bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
Illegal instruction: 4
```

with the choice of error being seemingly random. Furthermore if either example is compiled with `-O3` the compiler itself throws a `Segmentation fault: 11` itself. I get no warnings from gcc at any point, and I'm not able to figure out what's happening. Does anyone know why the second program fails while the first doesn't? Or better still how to fix the second one?

My gcc is `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)` and my kernel is `Darwin Kernel Version 12.1.0: Tue Aug 14 13:29:55 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.9.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64`.

**edit:** To be clear, I understand that what I'm trying to do is stupid. This code isn't going to run on the Curiosity rover, or the NYSE. I'm trying to understand more about how function pointers in (GNU) C work, and explain something interesting I found. I promise never to do anything like this in the real world.

Comment: Quote from the manual you've linked: "If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function has exited, all hell will break loose."

Comment: @Joulukuusi That would have been enough to deter me, had I not gotten it to work with the `int`s.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really work on my PC: it has just printed `2` when compiled without optimizations, but `3` when compiled with `-O3`. This one quit with a segmentation fault: http://ideone.com/rQiFT2

Comment: I guess you hit the “you may be lucky” part with your int thingy. As C has no native [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), you can't get currying that way.

Comment: Q: I'm honestly curious: if you want to do functional programming, why are you using C?  You just need to use C for this project (because of some requirement or another)?  Or you're just trying to be perverse?

Comment: @paulsm4 both really. I was writing something in C and was thinking about the best way to express it. I thought that a curried function would work, but I realised almost immediately after I started writing that C wasn't made for that sort of thing. But I was still curious so I came here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An interesting question and I took a look at the paper in the answer cited ([More functional reusability in C/C++/Objective-C with Curried functions](http://asg.unige.ch/site/papers/Dami91a.pdf)).

So following is a suggested path to where you might want to go.  I do not think this is truly a Curried function as I do not fully understand what the paper is talking about, not being a functional programmer.  However, doing a bit of work, I find an interesting application of some of this concept.  I am not sure this is what you want on the other hand, it kind of blows my mind that you can do this in C.

There seemed to be two problems.

First of all was to be able to handle arbitrary function calls with arbitrary argument lists.  The approach I took was to use standard C Library variable arguments functionality (va_list with the va_start(), va_arg(), and va_end() functions) and to then store the function pointer along with the provided arguments into a data area so that they could then be executed at a later time.  I borrowed and modified how the `printf()` function uses the format line to know how many arguments and their types are provided.

The next was the storage of the function and its argument list.  I just used a struct with some arbitrary size just to try out the concept.  This will need a bit more thought.

This particular version uses an array that is treated like a stack.  There is a function that you use to push some arbitrary function with its arguments onto the stack array  and there is a function that will pop the top most function and its arguments off of the stack array and execute it.

However you could actually just have arbitrary struct objects in some kind of a collection for instance a hash map and that might be very cool.

I just borrowed the signal handler example from the paper to show that the concept would work with that kind of an application.

So here is the source code and I hope it helps you come up with a solution.

You would need to add other cases to the switch so as to be able to process other argument types.  I just did a few for proof of concept.

Also this does not do the function calling a function though that would seem on the surface to be a fairly straightforward extension.  Like I said, I do not totally get this Curried thing.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

// a struct which describes the function and its argument list.
typedef struct {
    void (*f1)(...);
    // we have to have a struct here because when we call the function,
    // we will just pass the struct so that the argument list gets pushed
    // on the stack.
    struct {
        unsigned char myArgListArray[48];   // area for the argument list.  this is just an arbitray size.
    } myArgList;
} AnArgListEntry;

// these are used for simulating a stack.  when functions are processed
// we will just push them onto the stack and later on we will pop them
// off so as to run them.
static unsigned int  myFunctionStackIndex = 0;
static AnArgListEntry myFunctionStack[1000];

// this function pushes a function and its arguments onto the stack.
void pushFunction (void (*f1)(...), char *pcDescrip, ...)
{
    char *pStart = pcDescrip;
    AnArgListEntry MyArgList;
    unsigned char *pmyArgList;
    va_list argp;
    int     i;
    char    c;
    char   *s;
    void   *p;

    va_start(argp, pcDescrip);

    pmyArgList = (unsigned char *)&MyArgList.myArgList;
    MyArgList.f1 = f1;
    for ( ; *pStart; pStart++) {
        switch (*pStart) {
            case 'i':
                // integer argument
                i = va_arg(argp, int);
                memcpy (pmyArgList, &i, sizeof(int));
                pmyArgList += sizeof(int);
                break;
            case 'c':
                // character argument
                c = va_arg(argp, char);
                memcpy (pmyArgList, &c, sizeof(char));
                pmyArgList += sizeof(char);
                break;
            case 's':
                // string argument
                s = va_arg(argp, char *);
                memcpy (pmyArgList, &s, sizeof(char *));
                pmyArgList += sizeof(char *);
                break;
            case 'p':
                // void pointer (any arbitray pointer) argument
                p = va_arg(argp, void *);
                memcpy (pmyArgList, &p, sizeof(void *));
                pmyArgList += sizeof(void *);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    va_end(argp);
    myFunctionStack[myFunctionStackIndex] = MyArgList;
    myFunctionStackIndex++;
}

// this function will pop the function and its argument list off the top
// of the stack and execute it.
void doFuncAndPop () {
    if (myFunctionStackIndex > 0) {
        myFunctionStackIndex--;
        myFunctionStack[myFunctionStackIndex].f1 (myFunctionStack[myFunctionStackIndex].myArgList);
    }
}

// the following are just a couple of arbitray test functions.
// these can be used to test that the functionality works.
void myFunc (int i, char * p)
{
    printf (" i = %d, char = %s\n", i, p);
}

void otherFunc (int i, char * p, char *p2)
{
    printf (" i = %d, char = %s, char =%s\n", i, p, p2);
}

void mySignal (int sig, void (*f)(void))
{
    f();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i = 3;
    char *p = "string";
    char *p2 = "string 2";

    // push two different functions on to our stack to save them
    // for execution later.
    pushFunction ((void (*)(...))myFunc, "is", i, p);
    pushFunction ((void (*)(...))otherFunc, "iss", i, p, p2);

    // pop the function that is on the top of the stack and execute it.
    doFuncAndPop();

    // call a function that wants a function so that it will execute
    // the current function with its argument lists that is on top of the stack.
    mySignal (1, doFuncAndPop);

    return 0;
}
```

An additional bit of fun you can have with this is to use the `pushFunction()` function within a function that is invoked by `doFuncAndPop()` to have another function you can put onto the stack with its arguments.

For instance if you modify the function `otherFunc()` in the source above to look like the following:

```
void otherFunc (int i, char * p, char *p2)
{
    printf (" i = %d, char = %s, char =%s\n", i, p, p2);
    pushFunction ((void (*)(...))myFunc, "is", i+2, p);
}
```

if you then add another call to `doFuncAndPop()` you will see that first `otherFunc()` is executed then the call to `myFunc()` that was pused in `otherFunc()` is executed and then finally the `myFunc()` call that was pushed in the `main ()` is called.

**EDIT 2:**
If we add the following function this will execute all of the functions that have been put onto the stack.  This will allow us to basically create a small program by pushing functions and arguments onto our stack and then executing the series of function calls.  This function will also allow us to push a function without any arguments then push some arguments.  When popping functions off of our stack, if an argument block does not have a valid function pointer then what we do is to put that argument list onto the argument block on the top of the stack and to then execute that.  A similar change can be made to the function `doFuncAndPop()` above as well.  And if we use the pushFunction() operation in an executed function, we can do some interesting things.

Actually this could be the basis for a [Threaded Interpreter](http://www.scribd.com/doc/19746809/Threaded-Interpretive-Languages-Their-Design-and-Implementation).

```
// execute all of the functions that have been pushed onto the stack.
void executeFuncStack () {
    if (myFunctionStackIndex > 0) {
        myFunctionStackIndex--;
        // if this item on the stack has a function pointer then execute it
        if (myFunctionStack[myFunctionStackIndex].f1) {
            myFunctionStack[myFunctionStackIndex].f1 (myFunctionStack[myFunctionStackIndex].myArgList);
        } else if (myFunctionStackIndex > 0) {
            // if there is not a function pointer then assume that this is an argument list
            // for a function that has been pushed on the stack so lets execute the previous
            // pushed function with this argument list.
            int myPrevIndex = myFunctionStackIndex - 1;
            myFunctionStack[myPrevIndex].myArgList = myFunctionStack[myFunctionStackIndex].myArgList;
        }
        executeFuncStack();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:**
Then we make a change to `pushFunc()` to handle a double with the following additional switch:

```
case 'd':
  {
     double d;
     // double argument
     d = va_arg(argp, double);
     memcpy (pmyArgList, &d, sizeof(double));
     pmyArgList += sizeof(double);
   }
break;
```

So with this new function we can do something like the following.  First of all create our two functions similar to the original question.  We will use the pushFunction() inside one function to push arguments that are then used by the next function on the stack.

```
double f1 (double myDouble)
{
    printf ("f1 myDouble = %f\n", myDouble);
    return 0.0;
}

double g2 (double myDouble) {
    printf ("g2 myDouble = %f\n", myDouble);
    myDouble += 10.0;
    pushFunction (0, "d", myDouble);
    return myDouble;
}
```

New we use our new functionality with the following series of statements:

```
double xDouble = 4.5;
pushFunction ((void (*)(...))f1, 0);
pushFunction ((void (*)(...))g2, "d", xDouble);
executeFuncStack();
```

These statements will execute first the function `g2()` with the value of 4.5 and then the function `g2()` will push its return value onto our stack to be used by the function `f1()` which was pushed on our stack first.

Comment: Something else that is interesting is that you can use the pushFunction() function to put another function call on the stack.  See the edit I am adding at the bottom.

Comment: @luserdroog, an additional function allows for the execution of programs made up of function calls.  You create your program by doing a series of pushes of function calls onto our mini-stack and then call the executeFuncStack() to execute the series of functions.  And we add the ability to push a function without arguments and to then push the arguments that will be used by the function in a separate step.

Comment: @RichardChambers thanks for the fantastic answer. I think I may end up eventually trying to write something based on this to get a proper functional experience in C. I hope you won't be offended if I suggest this is a pretty good example of [Greenspun's Tenth Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule).

Comment: @SeanD, <laughter>  that is so funny!  not offended at all.  lisp is something I have wondered about ever since doing an emacs macro that did something simple years ago.  My first and last experience with lisp.

Comment: @RichardChambers I meant that *you* were inspired, and deserve a vote for that. Not that I mind the notifications, but I've made this a favorite, so I'll keep checking back. Not sure when I'll ever use this technique, but I'll keep in the back pocket just in case. :)

Comment: Browsing [interpreter] questions, I came across this potentially relevant paper: [A Hacker's Introduction to Partial Evaluation](http://wry.me/misc/peval.html).

Comment: @luserdroog, I kind of got lost in this paper.  Lisp code, Scheme, and the whole whole functional paradigm just looks like magic to me <laughter>.  I have taken a look at F# and intend to come back to it at some point just as a way of trying to understand it.  I ran into a C application that had a special purpose mini-language made up of a set of macros that were used to write code in a table that was interpreted in a state driven virtual machine.  It was kind of a high level assembler and kind of like the RPG II language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG)

Comment: I have the same difficulty. I thought I was doing fine until I realized I had begun skipping the code and skimming the text trying to find the "good part". I've read a great *about* lisp and FP in the past few years, but have somehow still managed *not to take the plunge*. Perhaps my ulterior motive is impeding me: I'm mostly looking for ideas to steal for my Postscript project(s).

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to rely on undefined behaviour: Once the inner function goes out of scope because the outer one does exit, the behaviour of calling that inner function through some pointer is undefined. Anything might happen. The fact that things accidentially worked for the integer case does not imply that you can expect the same for double, or that you can even expect the same for int over different compilers, different compiler versions, different compiler flags or different target architectures.

So don't rely on undefined behaviour. Don't claim to have “heed[ed] the warnings” when in fact you acted against those warnings. The warning clearly states:

> If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function has exited, all hell will break loose.

There are no [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) in C, so there can't be currying in this sense. You can get similar effects if you pass along some data to function invocations, but that will not look exactly like a normal function call, so it won't feel like normal currying. C++ has more flexibility there, as it allows objects to behave syntactically like functions. In the C++ world, currying is usually called “[binding](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html)” of function parameters.

If you really want to know why one piece of code worked but the other failed, you can take the assembly code (generated e.g. by `gcc -S -fverbose-asm`) and simulate the execution in your head, to see what happens to your data and stuff. Or you may use the debugger to see where things fail, or data locations change. Might take some work, and I doubt it's worth the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this is crazy and I've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for not getting it, but why don't you *wrap* instead of *curry*, since you're declaring functions at compile time anyway? The advantage of currying is - or at least, it seems to me - that you can define a partially applied function at runtime, but here you aren't doing this. Or am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Basic function summing its arguments
double g (double a, double b)
{
    return a+b;
}

double f1(double a)
{
    /* "1" can be replaced by a static initialized
       by another function, e.g.
       static double local_b = g(0, 1);
    */
    return g(a, 1);
}

int main () {
    printf ("(g(2))(1)=%f\n", f1(2));
}
```

Comment: The idea of Curry seems to be to allow a function to be used without modifying the function.  It reminds me of the Decorator Pattern in which you are adding decorations to an existing object in order to do some additional things or to provide additional flexibility.

Comment: You're quite right that this is the best thing to do here, and what I am actually using. The reason I'm looking at currying is because that's what would be idiomatic in Haskell, and I'm trying to see how far that approach would get in C, just because it becomes very elegant, especially when one is trying to do more sophisticated things involving producing lots of functions and passing them around.

Comment: You'd need to wrap each function with a CURRYABLE macro to generate at compile time a variadic-argument version of that function, then store a list of curries as (pointer to fn, fixed argument list). And there's still the question of handling the return value. This can be done with compiler help and in other languages; I'm afraid that C can't easily supply even the "create new function" feature, let alone the "identify arguments by name instead of incremental position" which contribute much to the usefulness of currying.

Comment: @RichardChambers, yes, and by wrapping a function in C we do not modify it. You can sort-of-decorate in C with wrappers, albeit without named arguments, which reduces the advantages of the thing -- you'd almost need a specific decorator for every different function.

Comment: I think the main benefit of currying over wrapping is that you can repeatedly curry with different values computed at runtime. You can't do that with a single wrapper function, because you have no place to store that additional argument.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version of above code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double (*function) (double,double);

// Basic function summing its arguments
double g (double a, double b)
{
        return a+b;
}

double f1(function wrapfunc,double a)
{
 /* "1" can be replaced by a static initialized
     by another function, e.g.
     static double local_b = g(0, 1);
 */
 return wrapfunc(a, 1);  
}

int main () {
        printf ("(g(2))(1)=%f\n", f1(g,2));
}
```

a bit more about different operation functions with sample parameter example

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define N 4

#define LOOP(i) for(i=0; i<N; i++)

#define F(i) ( (int(*)(int,int))opt[i] )
#define FI F(i)
#define FJ F(j)
#define FK F(k)


int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int sub(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
```

u    int mul(int a, int b) { return a * b; }

```
int div(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0 || a % b)
        return 2401;
    return a / b;
}

char whichOpt(int index)
{
    if (index == 0) return '+';
    else if (index == 1) return '-';
    else if (index == 2) return '*';
    return '/';
}

void howObtain24(int num[], void *opt[])
{
    int i, j, k, a, b, c, d;
    int ans=0;
    LOOP(i) LOOP(j) LOOP(k)
         LOOP(a) LOOP(b) LOOP(c) LOOP(d)
    {
        if (a == b || a == c || a == d || b == c || b == d || c == d)
            continue;
        if (FI(FJ(FK(num[a], num[b]), num[c]), num[d]) == 24) {
            std::cout << "((" << num[a] << whichOpt(k) << num[b] << ')'
                 << whichOpt(j) << num[c] << ')' << whichOpt(i) << num[d] << endl;
            ans++;
            continue;
        }
        if (FI(FJ(num[a], num[b]), FK(num[c], num[d])) == 24) {
            std::cout << '(' << num[a] << whichOpt(j) << num[b] << ')'
                 << whichOpt(i) << '(' << num[c] << whichOpt(k) << num[d] << ')' << endl;
            ans++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if(ans==0)
    std::cout << "Non-Answer" << std::endl;
    return;

}

//=======================================================================
int main() {

    int num[N];

    void *opt[N] = { (void *)add, (void *)sub, (void *)mul, (void *)div };

    std::cout << "Input 4 Numbers between 1 and 10\n"
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cin >> num[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        if (num[j] < 1 || num[j] > 10) {
            std::cout << "InCorrect Input\n"

            return 0;
        }
        howObtain24(num, opt);

        return 0;
}
```