# Unspecified parameters in function declaration

Tags: c

The following compiles and runs and returns 3 on gcc linux x64.

```
int f();
int main()
{
  return f(1,2,3);
}
int f(int a,int b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

Why is it useful to declare a function as `int f();` and later define parameters in the function's definition as in this example?

Comment: [Because history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074190).

Comment: You are demonstrating why for the whole of this millennium it has been a very bad idea to use non-prototype function declarations. Time to get a modern compiler and turn on enough warnings that the code shown won’t compile.