# Same program gives compiler error in one compiler and not the other

Tags: c

I'm studying Learn to Code with C by Simon Long.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/Essentials_C_v1.pdf 
on page 20 there is this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void)
 {
  int a = 0;
  while (a < 5)
{
  printf ("a is equal to %d\n", a);
  a++;
}
  printf ("a is equal to %d and I've finished\n", a);
}
```

But when I compile this I get this compiler error:

```
while-loop.c:3:1: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
  [-Wmain-return-type]
void main(void)
^
while-loop.c:3:1: note: change return type to 'int'
void main(void)
^~~~
int
1 warning generated.
```

Why is this? It seems that the author's compiler does not give error for this. Why the discrepancy?

When I change

```
void main (void)
```

to

```
int main (void)
```

it compiles fine.

Comment: `void main` is an extension that a compiler might or might not implement. The standard `main` return type is `int`.

Comment: I wouldn't trust learning from a book that has stuff like the wrong signature for `main()`.

Comment: Perhaps the author Simon Long learned from renowned C expert Herbert Schildt? ;-)

Comment: @Shawn I wouldn't trust a book with so many colored decorations per page.

Comment: @Shawn can you recommend a free book for C beginners?

Comment: @EugeneSh. what is your recommendation as a free book or online source? I know there so many.

Comment: @zeynel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [**5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**, paragraph 1 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1) (bolding mine):

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. **It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int** and with no parameters:
>
> ```
>      int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
>      int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

While `void main()` does fit in "or in some other implementation-defined manner", in my opinion a particular implementation-specific extension such as that doesn't belong in a beginner's text without at least some explanation as it will only lead to confusion later.

At least find a book that doesn't make the eyes hurt so much.

Comment: what's the difference btw `int main(void)` and `int main()` sir?

Comment: `int main(void)` - takes no parameters. `int main()` - takes unspecified number of parameters. Only the former should be used for function definitions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks firstly, what's the wrong(s) with the latter one sir? Even gcc accepts it w/o any error or warning.

Comment: @snr Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073893/c-unspecified-number-of-parameters-void-foo

Comment: @snr: Unless the compiler documentation explicitly lists it as a valid signature, `void main()` results in *undefined behavior*, meaning that it's considered erroneous code, but the compiler is not required to handle it in any particular way.  There are some (admittedly old and/or oddball platforms) where using `void main()` may result in code that crashes on startup.  Newer compilers tend to warn about it, but strictly speaking they are not *required* to.  That's the problem with a lot of undefined behavior, you may not get a warning about it.

Comment: @JohnBode thanks for your answer sir, but my question was interested in "formal parameters" of the main() function having the return type of _int_.

Comment: @snr - In a function *definition* (where you specify the function body), an empty parameter list means the same thing as a parameter list of `void` - the function takes no arguments.  So `int main(void) { ... }` and `int main( ) { ... }` both mean the same thing.  In a function *declaration* (where you only specify the function name and argument list), an empty parameter list means the function takes an *unspecified* number of arguments, so `int foo();` and `int foo(void);` mean *different* things.  As a matter of style, always use `void` instead of an empty parameter list for no arguments.

Comment: @JohnBode w.r.t. *an empty parameter list means the same thing as a parameter list of void* - Are you sure? https://ideone.com/vVPGNC vs https://ideone.com/961XJa

Comment: @EugeneSh.: As part of a function *definition*, yes.  6.7.6.3/14: "An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. **An empty
list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
function has no parameters.** The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the
parameters is supplied."

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Now, using an empty parameter list as opposed to `void` means the function declaration/definition is not a *prototype*, so no checks are made on the numbers and types of arguments in a function call.  Hence why your second example compiled.

Comment: @JohnBode would you mind showing your bolded saying by using ideone, with a small example?