How to do currying in C
In this code I am trying to return a function that can add ctx.a to passed argument x.
The intended answer is 4 but when running this code it prints 6.
What is going wrong here?
I have tried this code:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int a;
} ctx_t;

typedef void(*with_ctx)(int);

with_ctx create_handler(ctx_t ctx) {
  void handler(int x) {
    printf("%d\n", ctx.a + x);
  }

  return handler;
}

int main() {

  ctx_t ctx = { .a = 1 };
  with_ctx handler = create_handler(ctx);
  handler(3);

  return 0;
}


Standard C does not allow nested functions. If your compiler allows them, you need to find its documentation and figure out their semantics. My guess is that they do not create closures, so trying to do currying with them won't work.

What you wrote is invalid. Specifically, returning handler is invalid, because after create_handler() returns, handler becomes invalid. Furthermore, defining functions inside functions is not standard C, it is an extension that is supported by major compilers but definitely discouraged and does not behave as you would expect. There's no built-in feature in C that allows you to implement currying like this, i.e. like what you would call "closures" in other languages.

Hi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023261/is-there-a-way-to-do-currying-in-c did you try the search function?

Declaring functions inside functions is not supported in C. What happens, is that you are using a compiler that supports it as an extension on top of C. I thin only gcc supports it.

What is going wrong here?

What then happens is that the variable ctx stops existing after return handler;. The variable ctx scope inside create_handler stops existing after the function ends on }. So calling handler() will access some undefined region of memory, where ctx used to be. It is no longer there.
It is not possible to create lambdas in C programming language. See Is there a way to do currying in C? .

this code is actually test code, i actually want to use nftw() and a function pointer has to be passed in nftw as an argument. but the problem starts when i have to use a db in which i store path to every file in the directory. if i add a parameter to give db context in the function (the one to be passed in as argument), its signature changes and cant be used in nftw so i thought why not use a function in which i can define db and define function in it that uses the said db ctx and returns the function for nftw().

You asked xy question, you got xy answer. Consider posting another question specifically nftw and the problem you are facing. I do not know what is nftw and what library or your code you are working on.

If you are asking about nftw from posix https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/nftw.html , the function is not reentrant and not thread safe. Use a global variable for context or write your own nftw
